# Peripheral connections for the the ages

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I have a peripheral that has a 6 pin JST female connector that mates to the peripheral. The other end came with a 6 pin female JST connector that is decidedly NOT compatible with the Pi GPIO header. The first thing I did was strip off the female JST end for the Pi.

Now my question is, for a reliable, long-term, secure connection to the GPIO header, what is my best bet for a connection? I am thinking of bringing into play a cable with weatherproof connectors on each end, so as to ensure the peripheral can be move with respect to the Pi, and for reliability. Still, for connecting to the GPIO? I am almost certain directly soldering to the pins is not the way most people do it. Any tips?

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.  Lots of devices have pins.  Perhaps electronics exchange?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Like zero people with Pi do electronics.

Comment: @DavidLazar joan's point is that you are asking on a site where many of the readers are not familiar with electronic assemblies. You would have much better luck asking your question on the Electronics site, since there is nothing Pi-specific in the question.

Comment: I get it! I appreciate the hot tips... thanks to all. It is far better than crickets chirping!

Comment: @joan I'm not sure why this was closed, the question is regarding making a secure connection to the GPIO header which is raspberry pi specific.  The on-topic link specifically says `Raspberry Pi hardware, including GPIO and other related electronics.`

Comment: It is my view (shared by enough others) that the question could be asked of any device with header pins. 
 `Please make sure that your questions are intrinsically Raspberry Pi oriented. We have an unusual amount of "off-topic" questions because of the extensive overlap with our sibling sites at Unix & Linux, Stack Overflow, and Electrical Engineering. When in doubt, ask there first. Questions where the Raspberry Pi is not a significant factor will likely be closed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to find or create your own adapter cable.  If the pi is in a case/housing, run the wires through a hole in the case and tie a knot in the cable so the cable can't be pulled through and disconnected from the Pi easily.

I personally get an [Adafruit Perma-Proto HAT for Pi](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2310) as well as the [GPIO Header](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2222) and you could solder directly to that your own JST cable if you wish.  I've used PCB screw terminal blocks but they take up some space and the wires sometimes pop out when I'm trying to get others in.  A no-solder option would be the [Pi-EzConnect Terminal Block Breakout HAT](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2711).  You can also get cases that have room for hats, connectors, etc.  There are lots of options out there, especially HAT products, just got to look for what suits you best.

Comment: Outstanding! That makes total sense to me. So I just solder to the hat, and then attaching the hat to the Pi is nice and slick... low-cost, and should be reliable.

Comment: @DavidLazar You might need the brass standoffs as well, it would make it more secure, that shows under "Also Include" in those links.  The stacking header they show there is to allow stacking of HATs, probably don't need that one, just the header above.